# Selenium c# : How to catch exception from function in WebDriverWait().Until()

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, exception, webdriverwait

I use the following function to wait for a page to be fully loaded before processing it:

```
protected bool WaitForPageLoad(){
    return new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
}
```

Sometimes `IJavaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript()` return an `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException` and despite the fact that I enclose the `WaitForPageLoad()` call in a `try catch` block, that exception still isn't caught.

How do I catch it?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your webdriverwait to ignore certain exceptions.

You can use it like this:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException), typeof(NoSuchWindowException));
wait.Until(d=> ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
```